# What kind of punctuation marks to use in writing this?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, writing

We have something called *dhikr* in Islam.

We repeat the same word hundreds or thousands of times, e.g.

> Subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah

(It means far from any imperfection is Allah?).

Also,

> la ilahe ilallah   la ilahe ilallah  la ilahe ilallah   la lilahe ilallah la ilahe ilallah

(There is no deity worthy of worship other than Allah).

My question is: if I write in a notebook or format pages one hundred or one thousands of this words repeatedly one after the other example *subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah.....* until I reach the number one hundred or one thousand. What punctuation mark should I place between *subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah subhanallah* or *la ilahe ilallah 
  la ilahe ilallah   la ilahe ilallah*?

Should I place a comma like this

> subhanallah, subhanallah, subhanallah, subhanallah

or a period like below ?

> subhanallah. subhanallah. subhanallah. subhanallah. subhanallah. subhanallah. subhanallah. subhanallah. la ilahe ilallah. la ilahe ilallah. la ilahe ilallah. la ilahe ilallah. la ilahe ilallah. la ilahe ilallah. la ilahe ilallah

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question about the English Language or its usage.

Comment: This Q belongs on [writing.se]

Comment: This has rarely if ever cropped up in everyday English, Ibrahim, so no standard practice has been invented / established. To format, something like 'Try, try, try ... (to a total of 100)' might be used, but this might be considered disrespectful here. I'd use the comma-and-space myself if forced to come up with a solution, and make sure I had say 10 words a line, with identical lines, for (an attempt at!) ease of reading. But this essentially boils down to a style choice for those concerned only with the nuts and bolts of lovable old English. Perhaps you could ask a religious leader what ...

Comment: they would consider a respectful approach.

Comment: It's up to the author.

Answer (score 1):

*Chicago Manual of Style* (13th ed) says in section 5.56:

> For ease of reading, it is sometimes desirable to separate two identical or closely similar words with a comma, even though the sense or grammatical construction does not require such separation.

Comment: That's a valuable reference, Rajah. I've snaffled it. But I don't think they envisaged 100 identical words being juxtaposed.